# Ruby File Delete Cucumber

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm running tests where I download a PDF file from a webpage, confirm it's gone to the download folder then delete it (to stop the folder being overwhelmed with PDF's).

When trying to use a wild card in the filepath so that others can run this test on their machine, I get an error saying that the file doesn't exist.

This is my code:

```
pdf_file = ("C:/Users/**/Downloads/myfile.pdf")

And(/^I can see the downloaded PDF$/) do
  puts Dir['C:/**/**/Downloads/myfile.pdf'].last
 File.delete(pdf_file)
end
```

It's odd that the wildcards work when confirming within the Dir.

As soon as I put the actual username in the file path, it works.  Is there anyway to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm reading this correctly, but--based on the code--you are passing a string that contains asterisks to `File.delete`.  You need to call `Dir::[]` on that string to perform the wildcard conversion(s) before passing it to `File.delete`.  For example:

```
File.delete(Dir["C:/Users/**/Downloads/myfile.pdf"].last)
```